# Grape & Mongo, Rails & MySQL next?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, architecture

Currently I've got a daily web scrape happening which uses [node.io](http://node.io/) and puts the results into a Mongo database. I'm running map/reduce on some of the collections and Mongo seems to do what I need nicely.

I have the beginnings of a REST API using [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) and it seems to work very well.

Next step is to push on with the client facing side of the app...

I had already started setting up Rails and was going to use MySQL for the relational data. However, is this the best idea? Or, would it be better to continue to use Mongo for the rest of the app and rely on client side JS ([Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) / [Ember](http://emberjs.com/)) to handle view updates etc? I want to use the best tool for the job but also want to keep things as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends so much on the details of your app that it's impossible for us to answer objectively in its current form, I think.

However, my personal, subjective opinion would be stick with Mongo:

1. You'll have far fewer headaches only having to maintain one DBMS
2. Mongo is intrinsically less headachey than an RDBMS (in my opinion)
3. Mongo and Rails integration with Mongoid/MongoMapper is pretty good

Not sure what you mean by "rely on client side JS to handle view updates etc?" - can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for your input. By client side JS I really meant Backbone / Ember etc, something to handle updating views etc. I'm happy to go with Mongo. I think you're right, it would be much easier to stick to one DBMS rather than a mix.

Comment: No problem - I think what I meant was why does client side js impact on your choice of DBMS?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I think I was kind of asking two questions in one. One regarding the choice of DB, the other about whether or not to use Rails or to use a lighter solution. I'm happy sticking with Rails though so please disregard that question.